# How to eliminate the given item from a list?

Tags: python

```
item = 1
test_list = [1,1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1,2]
for i in test_list:
        if(i == item):
            test_list.remove(i)
  
print(test_list)
```

Expected otuput = `[3, 4, 6, 5, 2]`

But it is giving = `[3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2]`

Comment: Iterating a collection and removing/appending items into it simultaneously is wrong. Make a separate list, or use list comprehension with `filter`

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over a list that you are modifying.

Comment: item = 1
test_list = [1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2] 

while item in test_list:
    test_list.remove(item)
    
print(test_list)